# Swap Face Normals But Leave Texture in Sketchup

Tags: texture, sketchup

At some point, half my model in Sketchup apparently got the normals botched and I didn't notice before painting in all the materials. Now, if I fix the normals (i.e. reverse the face), the texture flips right along with it and I now need to untexture the wrong sides and retexture the right sides. Is there a way to swap the normals/faces but leave my material on the side it was before flipping?

Answer (score 1):

No. SketchUp does support dual-faced materials, so you could declare the relevant material double-sided.